# Proj4s.js Library Transformation Accuracy Documentation

Tags: coordinate-system, proj

I am using proj4s.js for transforming between coordinate systems for a GIS web application. Is there any documentation out there on transformations accuracy provided by the library?

Comment: I think its a very good question. Transformations can have a lot of math operations and rounding errors could stack up. I think though that for uses like web cartography, its more than enough. But I wouldn't use it where i need great precision (0.00x meter)